# Spring Security does not intercept requests

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a legacy application in which I have added Spring Web MVC libraries in order to expose a new Rest API.

I am struggling integrating spring-security in order to  intercept the incoming requests. I have set up a security configuration class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();

   }
}
```

and a security application initializer

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends   
 AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
 }
```

following relevant guides.

Using debugger I verified that during initializing my configuration class is loaded. My problem is that my requests are not intercepted as expected.

Comment: Is your SecurityConfig  class annotated with @Configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using Spring MVC, go to your class that initializes your application. If you're using Java Config, it most likely extends `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`.

Add your `SecurityConfig` to its "root config classes":

```
public class MySpringMmvcInitializer extends 
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    ...

    @Override
    protected abstract Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ..., SecurityConfig.class};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the @configuration annotation, try this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();

   }
}
```